# MongoDB: find documents that match the most tags

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my meteor app, I have a huge collection of documents, each with a field `tags`, basically like this:

```
{..., tags: ["a","b","c"], ...},
{..., tags: ["a","b","d"], ...},
{..., tags: ["b","c","e"], ...},
{..., tags: ["x","y","z"], ...},
....
```

Now i want to query the collection on the server with some tags, eg: `["a","d","y"]` and get all results that match at least one tag, and the resultset sorted by the *number of matching tags*. So, in the exampleset the result should be:

```
{..., tags: ["a","b","d"], ...},
{..., tags: ["a","b","c"], ...},
{..., tags: ["x","y","z"], ...}
```

because the first doc has two matches, `"a"` and `"d"`, and the other two elements have one match, `"a"` and `"y"`.

Currently I know that I can use `$in` to match all documents that have at least one match, `$all` to get all documents where every tag matches, but this doesn't cut it somehow. I could also use mongoDB's aggregate framework if needed.

What would the needed query look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I could also use mongoDB's aggregate framework if needed.*

You need to use the the aggregation pipeline, which can be written as below:

- `Match` the documents having at least one matching value in the tags
  array.
- We will be unwinding and working on the tags array, so keep a copy of
  the tags array in each record.
- `Unwind` the `tags` array.
- `Match` the records which have their tags value present in the input array.
- `Group` by the `_id` field and calculate the number of documents that have matched.
- `Sort` the groups based on their number of matches.
- `project` the required fields along with the original tags array copy we had created.

Code:

```
var inp = ["a","d","y"];

db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"tags":{$in:inp}}},
{$project:{"tagsCopy":"$tags","tags":1}},
{$unwind:"$tags"},
{$match:{tags:{$in:inp}}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","noOfMatches":{$sum:1},"tags":{$first:"$tagsCopy"}}},
{$sort:{noOfMatches:-1}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"noOfMatches":1,tags:1}} //remove noOfMatches and 
                                            //add other required 
                                            //fields which are necessary.
])
```

o/p:

```
{ "noOfMatches" : 2, "tags" : [ "a", "b", "d" ] }
{ "noOfMatches" : 1, "tags" : [ "x", "y", "z" ] }
{ "noOfMatches" : 1, "tags" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

Comment: Most Welcome.;-) As a side question, why do you choose meteor over nodejs when meteor has very limited support for aggregation?

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate <-- for example. Aggregation in Meteor works okay. The point of using Meteor is the concept of my app *except* this query. Many client-heavy computations distributed over active users and (soft) realtime capabilities. (kinda news aggregator).

Comment: Follow up: by skipping the $tagsCopy entirely in the whole pipeline (so just tags, _id and sum are ever used) reduces the processing time from 1300ms to <=12ms for a collection of 2300 documents (each with ~15 tags). Fairly impressive. Tested on early 2013 rMBP.

Comment: I have collection like, `{"_id": "test-id", {"val" {"tags": ["a", "b", "c"]}}}`. How can I query for that?